# Are iphone 5 earphones compatible with iphones 3G and 4s?

Tags: iphone

Are the earphones that come with an iphone 5 compatible with iphones 3 and 4?

Comment: @Buscar Meta.SE: [Embrace the non-Googlers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as the earphones both use the 3.5mm headphone jack available on the iPhone 3G and 4s.